# How to repair corrupt pendrive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, gparted

I have an HP pendrive of 16GB. One day my little brother tried to make a bootable Hackintosh using that pendrive and we had a power cut when the write process was going on (my brother was using Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) hackintosh).  After that happened, I tried to format it with [GParted](http://gparted.org) but it gave me the following error message below; Is there a way to fix this
 pendrive?

[image: gparted details]

Comment: Assuming you don't care about its contents, just run `shred -n 1 -v /dev/sdX` (with the correct device node corresponding to the USB drive) to erase everything on the drive, then create a new partition using GParted again.

Comment: @mukund-swaminathan There is an option in Gparted to delete partition table of the device. Have you deleted it, re-created it with MSDOS compatibility and then created a new partition with you choice of filesystem? Did you ran into same error?